# Docker copy cacerts file from JRE

Tags: java, linux, docker, dockerfile

The `cacerts` file seems to differ between builds. When attempting to extract this file from the container for analysis something seems to be blocking it. Has anyone seen `docker cp` unable to find a file that is very evidently there (`ls` finds it on the box with no symlinks in the path)

ZSH output:

```
➜  ~ sudo docker cp 664750c4459c:/opt/jre/lib/security/cacerts .
Error: No such container:path: 664750c4459c:/opt/jre/lib/security/cacerts
➜  ~ docker run --rm -it 664750c4459c ls /opt/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/opt/jre/lib/security/cacerts
➜  ~ docker run --rm -it 664750c4459c ls /opt/jre/lib/security        
blacklisted.certs       default.policy
cacerts                 public_suffix_list.dat
```

Comment: You're giving it an image, not a container.  While you could create a container to do `docker cp` from, and then delete it afterwards, easier to just do `docker run --rm -it $image cat /opt/jre/lib/security/cacerts >extracted`

Comment: Thanks! I ended up mounting a volume and copying it there :)